# html:options calls get before set -> null pointer

Tags: java, properties, struts, struts-1

I have the following:

```
    <html:select property="myObject.value">
        <html:options property='myMap(someKey)'/>
    </html:select>
```

Where `map(someKey)` is set in the action. I've also created these methods in the form:

```
public void setMyMap( final Map<String, Collection<String>> map )
{
    myMap = map;
}

public Map<String, Collection<String>> getMyMap()
{
    return myMap;
}
```

This almost seems to work, but occasionally `myMap(someKey)` is accessed before the appropriate `Action` is even hit, leading to null pointers. What am I doing wrong, here?

**Edit:**
If I use a LazyMap to work around this issue, I avoid null pointers until the action sets the form up. I'd still like to know why this is happening, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [LazyMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LazyMap.html) or upgrade to Struts 2/3, so someone might actually be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

How have you determine the order in which the access occurs relative to the Action firing? Since `setMyMap` just stores a reference, one possibility is that the caller is running on a different thread and modifying the map after setting it.